# Performance issues with WPF DataGrid CheckBox column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF project with DataGrid. It has 500 dynamically added columns. It works fine with data types like integer or string. But if I make it 500 boolean columns, with checkboxes - DataGrid takes few seconds to scroll. Is it possible to optimize the boolean column/checkboxes somehow?

My DataGrid is defined like this:

```
<ext:ExtDataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="3"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataTableSample1, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding DataTableSample1SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ext:ExtDataGrid>
```

ItemsSource is a DataTable object, columns added like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    DataColumn dataColumnBoolean = new DataColumn(i.ToString());
    dataColumnBoolean.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Boolean");
    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumnBoolean);
}
```

Comment: side note: you can write `typeof(bool)` instead of `Type.GetType("System.Boolean")`. it is also possible to add dataColumn with type in one line : `dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(bool));`, without creating instance (Add will return newly added DatColumn object)

Comment: What is `ExtDataGrid`?

Comment: Just some extended DataGrid with few events .... problem remains exactly as I described, if I change XAML to simple DataGrid